# Basic question about improper integral

Tags: integration

If I have the evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x^3}dx$ can I solve it by evaluating $$\lim\limits_{a \to0^{-}}\int_{-1}^{a}\frac{1}{x^3}dx+\lim\limits_{b\to 0^{+}}\int_{b}^{1}\frac{1}{x^3}dx~\qquad ?$$

Comment: Do you know about the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)?

Comment: Yet, just wanted to know if it theoretically be solved this way

Comment: I think I fixed the limits of your integration to what you should've meant. If I am incorrect I apologize: feel free to revert. But notice that neither of your limits converge.

Comment: @gbox: Your approach is correct. You will find that neither limit exists, so the improper integral does not exist.

Comment: Don't forget the $\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Those limits are $-\infty,\infty$ respectively. There is no coherent meaning  in $-\infty+\infty.$

Answer (score 2):

The integral $I$ as given by

$$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x^3}\,dx$$

does not exist.  To see this, we write the integral as the improper Riemann integral

$$\begin{align}
I&=\lim_{a\to 0^-}\int_{-1}^a\frac{1}{x^3}\,dx+\lim_{b\to 0^+}\int_{b}^1\frac{1}{x^3}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^-}\left(\frac12 -\frac1{2a^2}\right)-\lim_{b\to 0^+}\left(\frac12 -\frac1{2a^2}\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Note that neither of the limits on the right-hand side of $(1)$ exists.

However, the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral of interest does exist since

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^3}\,dx\right)&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x^3}\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x^3}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac12\left(1-\frac1{\epsilon^2}\right)-\frac12\left(1-\frac1{\epsilon^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$